# RandomForest for one class and GradientBoosting for another class

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

On one of my projects which I am working upon, RandomForest is giving me accurate results for class 1 and Gradient Boosting Classifier is giving me accurate results for class 0. I want to use both of them i.e. best of both classifiers. Is it possible in Python Sklearn. I tried using Voting Classifier (soft option with different weights) but it is not helping my cause much.

In details this is the problem, when I am using `RandomForest` classifier on test set (for a binary classification task), this is the confusion matrix -

```
array([[5230, 7656],
       [ 683, **3340**]], dtype=int64)
```

and, when I am using `GradientBoostingClassifier` on same test data, this is the confusion matrix I am getting -

```
array([[**11404**,  1482],
       [ 2183,  1840]], dtype=int64)
```

As it can be seen that RF is predicting class 1 (with 3340) correctly while GBM is predicting class 0 (with 11404) correctly. How can I use both these classifiers in some sort of ensemble method so that I can use RF for Class 1 and GBM for class 0?

Can anyone please help me on this?

Cheers!

Comment: could you please formulate what you want to achieve better, and paste a reproducible and simplified code you have here?

Comment: then please paste the confusion matrices for each method in your question description.

Comment: Hi Adrin, I have edited my question now. Let me know if its still unclear.

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve probabilities for the classes from the classifiers? You could manually combine the class probabilities from both classifiers and increase the weights of class 1 in RF and class 0 in GBM.

Comment: Hi Pschill, yes, class probabilities can be derived. Could you please elaborate in details, what exactly you meant by manually combine the class probabilities and increase the weights? A sample code could be immensely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the columns of your confusion matrices, you realize that one method is biased in favour of class 1 ('GradientBoostingClassifier'), and the other method is biased towards class 2 (`RandomForest`).

You should also realize that both methods you're using are ensemble methods themselves.

To understand the problem better, assume you have `method 1` which predicts class 1 as output, regardless of the input, and `method 2` predicting class 2 as the output regardless of the input. Now try to calculate the confusion matrices of these two methods. For `method 1` it will look like:

```
array([[12886, 0],
       [ 4023, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

And for `method 2:

```
array([[0, 12886],
       [0, 4023]], dtype=int64)
```

You should also familiarize yourself with [precision and recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall).

So what I'm saying, is none of those two methods you're using are actually really good at one class. They're just biased in favour of one class, with the cost of false positives and false negatives in the other class. An ensemble of these two methods may improve your performance, but it can't do what you're asking.

What you're asking is basically: use method 1 if input is class 1, and method 2 if input is class 2. Now think about it, if you knew which class your input belongs to, you wouldn't be applying any of those classification methods at all, would you? ;)

**Edit**: if you want to do an ensemble of the two methods, you can use the estimated probabilities of the methods. It's important to remember that in the case of both these methods, the given probabilities are estimations, since none of the methods are probabilistic methods.

Assume the probability of input `X` being a member of class `y`, estimated by method `m` is written as: `P(y|X, m)`. Then you can have:

```
log(P(0|X)) = \sum{m \in M} log(P(0|X, m))
log(P(1|X)) = \sum{m \in M} log(P(1|X, m))
```

where `M` is the set of all the models you have in the pool. Of course you can calculated a weighted sum of logs if for some reason you trust one method more than the other.

Comment: Thanks Adrin, I agree my question was not correctly put. GBM performed exceptionally well on training data (using cross validation) but this training data was upsampled (class 1 upsampled). RF's performance on training data was not that great. When I used GBM hoping it will do well on test data (without sampling), this is the result I got. So my question then would be - should I then go ahead and use GBM henceforth for future unseen test examples or do something else? I am a bit confused now :D. I know about Precision Recall concept, that's why posed this question here.

Comment: and I am fine with anything which improves the current performance and ensembling sounds like it can result in some improvement. If this is the case, will sklearn's VotingClassifier help and if yes, then how to select weights under soft voting?